# Collection of Radiobutton groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

How do I post response from `radiobutton` groups back to controller?

Scenarios:

Patient1   oAccept       oReject

Patient2   oAccept       oReject

---

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveResponse", "Account", null,
                               FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {

@model List<Patients>
    foreach(var patient in Model)
    {
    <label>@Html.RadioButton(patient.PatientID, "True")Accept</label>
    <label>@Html.RadioButton(patient.PatientID, "False")Reject</label>
    }
}
```

Lets say, user clicks Accept for *patient1* and then for *patient2*. Let say, he clicks Reject. In controller, action method how do I accept these responses.  Responses like "Patient1 True" "Patient2 False"  SaveResponse(....)?

Thanks for help.